# Can't boot into a usb drive

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub, uefi, boot-loader

On my **windows 10** system I **can't boot** into a parrot os **gpt formatted** pendrive. I used **rufus** to format it. Whenever i choose the pendrive from boot menu i get the **grub command line**. Then i tried formatting my **pendrive as mbr** and then i tried booting from it and it booted successfully. But i still can't install it because my hdd is in gpt. I can live boot into parrot os. I also can't use chroot from live boot as i dont have linux installed. I don't know why am i getting the grub command line as I don't have any linux ditro installed in my system.

Comment: Have you changed the boot order in BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few causes for this. The most common are:

- Your BIOS has an option to boot from USB, and it is disabled
- SecureBoot is stopping it.
- BitLocker is enabled and interfering.

I am honestly not sure why the second one would stop the Boot partition from using the USB, but I know from experience that it can and will.

The first 2 (and sometimes the 3rd) can be addressed via the BIOS settings menu on your device.

In fact, I can almost guarantee, even before knowing all the details, that the solution to your issue is in these settings.

MY ADVICE:

boot into your BIOS settings just to see what options you are given. That said, **DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING HERE THAT YOU DO NOT KNOW WHAT IT DOES!!** Many great devices have been destroyed via a bad setting in the BIOS menu. That said, there is a plethora of information on these features online.

ONE EXAMPLE POSSIBILITY:

You can change the priority of available drives. You can use this feature to give your boot drive first priority (but it still won't work if 'boot from USB' is disabled.)

**EDIT**

Check your BIOS settings once more. If you are getting errors Due to a missing GPT partition then your changes must not have saved. GPT is an EFI only feature. It is referring to the `/boot` drive, which EFI uses to get FS locations for the various Operating systems on a disk(s).

In other words,

gpt --> efi;  efi --> gpt; package deal. (obviously, you will still have a gpt in legacy mode. your BIOS just won't use it. It uses a bit of code inside the mbr sector of the drive called "master partition table." gpt is "general partition table" and is uefi's way of storing / retrieving the same data.)

Comment: i have secure boot disabled and i also have enabled usb boot. But why can i boot my usb in mbr format ?

Comment: Do u mean with uefi disabled? This used to be a thing, but most distros are uefi compatible now. Just run the live boot in legacy mode, and the installation should create an entry in the efi boot volume. In efi mode, the boot software only sees devices that have an entry. Once installed, you should be able to switch back into efi mode. If it is dual-boot, dont start windows without efi enabled. This can mess it up. If you are just using live boot (not installing) you may just need to switch back & forth. Efi is different from 1 system to the next. Its just a standard

Comment: It shouldn't matter if your hard drive is in gpt. You can create partitions that use gpt alongside legacy mbr type partitions, on a single hard drive. gpt just means that it has an extra partition with boot info from each source "/boot/efi." Switching between just means enabling / disabling boot from that partition.

Comment: yes i have uefi enabled. But it doesn't works so i enabled legacy and formated my pendrive as mbr and then i tried installing it from live boot installer. in last it showed a message boost.python error in job 'bootloader' gpt label conatains no boot partition

Comment: Afaik legacy mode does not use GPT partitions. It uses MBR to get boot data. GPT is what EFI uses instead of MBR. Thats the only reason I asked. Unless I am missing something, it doesn't make sense that you would be getting an error about missing EFI partitionn if you are in legacy mode. I would check BIOS settings one more time.

Comment: gpt is guid partion table

Comment: Yea and it is part of the efi standard. It is a block in memory that holds references to other blocks. MBR uses its own system for discovery.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Balena Etcher](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher) instead of Rufus to create the bootable USB. Then you should ensure that CSM boot is disabled in your BIOS.

Now you should be able to choose a different device to boot from the BIOS boot menu. Select your usb drive.

IMO, Rufus makes the process of creating a bootable usb too complex. Etcher should just work.

If it still doesn't work, I would blame it on the Parrot OS ISO. Try making a live USB of another distro like [Linux Mint XFCE](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=290) and see if it works. If it does, report an issue to Parrot devs.

BTW, here is how you can absolutely make sure you have booted into EFI mode and not legacy mode -

Execute `ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars` in a terminal. If it shows the directory output without errors, it is booted in EFI mode. Else it has been booted in CSM/BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Intel Optane**, it may cause some trouble. I once had a similar issue while trying to install Ubuntu (honestly, I've just disabled it). You'd probably want to check that, and maybe try disabling it to make sure it is not causing any inconvenience.

**Operate carefully**, make a **backup** of important data, and take the necessary **precautions** to **avoid data loss**.